# Representing a correlation matrix without a "classical" heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, heatmap, complex-networks

I'm doing some analysis on a complex network. I have computed the degree correlation matrix, which looks like this:

```
data[1:5, 1:5] 

    1  2  3  4  5
1   6 19 11 16  5
2  19 10 16 12  6
3  11 16  7 11 10
4  16 12 11  5  9
5   5  6 10  9  8
```

And I'd like to plot it to obtain something akin to this:
[image: plot]

I've tried to use ggplot but the results are not at all satisfying, this is my code:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
data = melt(data) 
#The "melt" function was used to turn the matrix in a three column dataframe with columns named "Var1",
"Var2", and "value"

ggplot(data = data) +
theme_bw() +
geom_tile(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
scale_fill_viridis(name = "") +
labs(x = "k2", y = "k1")
```

And this is what I get:

[image: plot2]

Is there any way to fix it?

P.S. Sorry if I couldn't post the images directly, but my reputation is not high enough

EDIT: I'm putting here the `dput()` output of my matrix, as asked in the comments:

```
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 4, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 
3, 0, 3, 6, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 6, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 5, 
6, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 1, 6, 3, 1, 
3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 9, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 7, 3, 6, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 5, 1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 0, 0, 
0, 4, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 6, 1, 5, 
3, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 0, 2, 3, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 3, 2, 6, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 
6, 1, 2, 0, 4, 2, 4, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 6, 
5, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 4, 9, 3, 0, 4, 1, 5, 4, 7, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 1, 
4, 3, 6, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 6, 2, 1, 0, 1, 5, 1, 
0, 5, 1, 7, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 6, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 
0, 3, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 2, 6, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 6, 3, 6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 3, 9, 5, 0, 3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 4, 2, 4, 6, 
3, 4, 3, 12, 0, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 
0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 
1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 
2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 
3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 
1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 
2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 5, 4, 3, 7, 4, 3, 0, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 6, 6, 1, 
5, 3, 6, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 5, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 2, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 4, 
2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1, 3, 1, 7, 5, 3, 6, 2, 1, 1, 
0, 6, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 3, 1, 9, 5, 5, 6, 5, 7, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 10, 5, 
7, 5, 8, 3, 7, 3, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 7, 2, 0, 4, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 5, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 
1, 0, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 6, 6, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 2, 4, 3, 2, 
2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 7, 4, 0, 3, 6, 0, 2, 4, 4, 10, 
6, 3, 7, 5, 5, 10, 3, 11, 5, 6, 12, 11, 10, 6, 9, 2, 5, 12, 9, 
2, 5, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2, 1, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 5, 4, 12, 
1, 3, 3, 3, 8, 3, 1, 6, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 6, 
4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 4, 5, 5, 1, 6, 7, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 
1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 2, 1, 5, 0, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 6, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 
6, 3, 9, 6, 4, 3, 9, 4, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2, 2, 7, 5, 1, 1, 4, 3, 6, 
1, 1, 0, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
6, 3, 6, 12, 1, 2, 6, 5, 8, 3, 10, 12, 7, 9, 6, 3, 11, 4, 13, 
7, 7, 12, 2, 1, 5, 3, 9, 11, 0, 9, 11, 0, 17, 3, 3, 0, 4, 6, 
3, 1, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 6, 3, 0, 7, 4, 3, 3, 0, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 
2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 3, 7, 5, 11, 3, 3, 
4, 11, 7, 7, 8, 5, 8, 7, 7, 9, 8, 2, 4, 8, 3, 0, 3, 10, 4, 7, 
0, 3, 0, 3, 4, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 
1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 8, 1, 6, 10, 
4, 8, 7, 8, 4, 6, 4, 5, 0, 3, 3, 1, 8, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 
0, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 6, 7, 
6, 4, 6, 3, 5, 9, 13, 3, 5, 6, 4, 4, 9, 7, 11, 8, 3, 5, 15, 6, 
1, 5, 3, 8, 14, 4, 3, 0, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 6, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 12, 8, 4, 4, 
7, 3, 8, 10, 4, 4, 4, 13, 9, 8, 4, 5, 13, 9, 1, 6, 7, 3, 7, 3, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 5, 0, 4, 3, 2, 
3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 4, 2, 11, 3, 4, 4, 7, 0, 7, 4, 9, 4, 2, 
4, 8, 4, 0, 0, 6, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 9, 0, 4, 0, 7, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 
3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 6, 3, 
2, 10, 1, 3, 6, 12, 1, 7, 8, 7, 13, 4, 2, 6, 6, 8, 2, 10, 9, 
1, 4, 7, 5, 12, 2, 2, 0, 6, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 
5, 9, 7, 11, 9, 8, 6, 2, 5, 6, 5, 9, 8, 1, 3, 5, 3, 10, 3, 3, 
0, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 7, 4, 9, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 6, 5, 
2, 4, 2, 6, 6, 0, 5, 4, 1, 8, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 4, 2, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 0, 8, 6, 4, 0, 4, 2, 6, 0, 3, 5, 3, 
9, 3, 1, 0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 5, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 5, 
0, 2, 5, 2, 4, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 6, 
4, 2, 12, 3, 3, 7, 9, 2, 8, 4, 15, 13, 6, 10, 9, 6, 2, 3, 5, 
8, 3, 8, 9, 7, 20, 6, 4, 0, 7, 6, 2, 2, 4, 1, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 9, 4, 2, 5, 
11, 5, 3, 5, 6, 9, 9, 9, 8, 6, 6, 4, 8, 3, 2, 3, 6, 4, 14, 2, 
2, 0, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
5, 0, 2, 1, 9, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 3, 0, 8, 3, 0, 1, 5, 
2, 6, 2, 2, 0, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 11, 3, 10, 3, 
3, 7, 3, 7, 5, 4, 5, 5, 9, 6, 4, 5, 4, 6, 14, 2, 4, 0, 8, 2, 
3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 
0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 3, 0, 1, 4, 1, 8, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1, 3, 1, 
7, 4, 1, 2, 6, 4, 6, 7, 5, 0, 6, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 6, 6, 6, 3, 5, 3, 1, 5, 0, 4, 3, 4, 6, 
17, 5, 7, 8, 14, 7, 9, 12, 10, 8, 9, 2, 20, 14, 1, 6, 14, 6, 
10, 5, 6, 0, 9, 9, 10, 7, 9, 4, 7, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 4, 
3, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 2, 7, 5, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 4, 2, 
1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 
3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 7, 6, 4, 3, 6, 
1, 7, 2, 0, 1, 8, 6, 9, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 5, 2, 1, 2, 7, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 
4, 6, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 1, 5, 1, 6, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 9, 1, 
1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 
4, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 3, 2, 10, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 
2, 4, 7, 1, 4, 0, 5, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 3, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 4, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, 9, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 
4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 
0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 7, 4, 3, 2, 7, 3, 
2, 7, 1, 2, 5, 0, 4, 3, 6, 10, 2, 6, 0, 7, 5, 3, 10, 4, 3, 4, 
6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), dim = c(75L, 75L), dimnames = list(
    c("2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
    "14", "15", "16", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
    "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", 
    "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", 
    "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", 
    "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", 
    "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", 
    "75", "77", "79", "81"), c("2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "18", "19", 
    "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
    "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", 
    "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", 
    "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
    "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", 
    "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "77", "79", "81")))
```

Comment: Do you want a different color scheme? What exactly you mean by "classical". Can you share a bit more of your matrix? E.g. 20x20?

Comment: My matrix is 75x75; the main thing is, I'd like to remove those white lines in my plot, make it "prettier". Oh, and by "classical", I meant the kind of heatmap made with functions such as heatmap(), the ones divided in a grid with outlines on each cell

Comment: Please share your data in a reproducible format such as a `dput()` so we can copypaste to tun the code and test it. You need to define "prettier". If you want advice about general data visualization this is not the right site for that. This site is for specific programming questions.

Comment: @MrFlick I was mostly thinking about finding a way to remove the white lines (or a reason to why I couldn't remove them). By the way, I added the dput() output

Comment: You essentially have unobserved data. For example or Var 1, you don't have any values at 4 or 17. How do you want those represented on the graph? Do you just want to fill them in as zeros?

Comment: @MrFlick oh right, I thought it would fill them in automatically, I'm sorry. Yes filling them in with zeroes would be perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the lines because you have missing values. The full range is not represented in your data. Here's one way to fill in the missing values using `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

full_range <- function(x) seq(min(x), max(x))
data %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("Var1") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Var1, names_to="Var2") %>% 
  mutate(across(Var1:Var2, as.numeric)) %>% {
    d <- .
    expand_grid(Var1=full_range(d$Var1), Var2=full_range(d$Var2)) %>% 
      left_join(d) %>% 
      replace_na(list(value=0))
  } %>% 
  ggplot() +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_tile(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "") +
  labs(x = "k2", y = "k1")
```

that looks like this
[image]